# I've searched and I cannot seem to get the attribute of an xml element based on the attribute of a sibling xml element in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xelement

Here is my sample xml:

```
<customers group="A">
  <customer ID="1234" phone="555-555-0123" name="Golf Clubs International">
    <services>
      <service type="Golf" premise="89645" priority="0" />
    </services>
    <customFields>
      <customField key="address" value="5431 E Golf Way, Altanta, GA, 31111" />
      <customField key="connection" value="CONNECTED" />
    </customFields>
  </customer>
```

I need to return the customField address value where the service equals 89645. I've tried several different ways using XElement but none of them seem to filter for what I need and even when I get it to filter, I don't know how to re-navigate to get to the sibling element's attribute. Here are some of the things that I've tried to get to filter for the premise attribute. I've used this site for several years and this is the first time I was stumped enough to post a question.

```
        IEnumerable<XElement> tests =
            from el in cust.Elements("services")
            where (string)el.Elements("service").Attributes("premise").ToString() == ID
            select el;

        var y = cust.Element("customers")
                    .Elements("services")
                    .Where(b => b.Element("service").Value == ID)
                    .SingleOrDefault();

        var x = from a in cust.Elements("service")
                where a.Attribute("premise").Value == ID
                select cust.Elements("customfields").Elements("customfield").Attributes("key");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using a dictionary in this case.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication58
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"C:\TEMP\TEST.XML";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var query = doc.Descendants("customer").Select(x => new{
                premise = (string)x.Descendants("service").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("premise"),
                customFields = x.Descendants("customField").GroupBy(y => (string)y.Attribute("key"), z => (string)z.Attribute("value"))
                .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, z => z.FirstOrDefault())
            }).ToList();

            var results = query.Where(x => x.premise == "89645").FirstOrDefault();


        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is a one statement solution

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

```
var query = doc.Descendants("customer").Select(x => new {
    premise = (string)x.Descendants("service").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("premise"),
    customFields = x.Descendants("customField").GroupBy(y => (string)y.Attribute("key"), z => (string)z.Attribute("value"))
    .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, z => z.FirstOrDefault())
}).Where(x => x.premise == "89645")
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This worked very well, thank you so much. Just curious though, how would you go about debugging the query if its all in one statement?

Comment: I added a one statement solution.  I thought it was easier to understand if I posted the solution in two pieces.

Comment: the two pieces helped a lot and I appreciate you posting the single statement also.

Answer (score 0):

For VB'ers that might find this.

First some sample data

```
    Dim xe As XElement

    xe = <customers group="A">
             <customer ID="1234" phone="555-555-0123" name="Golf Clubs International">
                 <services>
                     <service type="Golf" premise="89645" priority="0"/>
                 </services>
                 <customFields>
                     <customField key="address" value="5431 E Golf Way, Altanta, GA, 31111"/>
                     <customField key="connection" value="CONNECTED"/>
                 </customFields>
             </customer>
             <customer ID="567" phone="555-555-0123" name="Golf Clubs International">
                 <services>
                     <service type="Golf" premise="54698" priority="0"/>
                 </services>
                 <customFields>
                     <customField key="address" value="5431 E Golf Way, Altanta, GA, 31111"/>
                     <customField key="connection" value="CONNECTED"/>
                 </customFields>
             </customer>
             <customer ID="890" phone="555-555-0123" name="Golf Clubs International">
                 <services>
                     <service type="Golf" premise="89645" priority="0"/>
                 </services>
                 <customFields>
                     <customField key="address" value="718 W. High, Jefferson City, MO 65101"/>
                     <customField key="connection" value="CONNECTED"/>
                 </customFields>
             </customer>
         </customers>
```

then the steps to get the address

```
    Dim rslts As IEnumerable(Of XElement)

    'first get service equals 89645, using above there are two
    rslts = From el In xe...<service>
            Where el.@premise = "89645"
            Select el

    'for each of those find the address
    For Each rel As XElement In rslts
        Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
        ie = rel.Parent.Parent.<customFields>.<customField>.Where(Function(cfel)
                                                                      Return cfel.@key = "address"
                                                                  End Function)

        For Each a As XElement In ie
            Debug.WriteLine(a.@value)
        Next
    Next
```

The queries could be shortened but this code is to illustrate what is going on.